# dictionary update sequence element error

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-3.5

I have several dictionary files, I want this code to open each file and add it to a set, for later comparison and matching. Basically I have a different list of all permutations of all possible characters and I need to know if permutation is in dictionary. But when I try to make a set with all dictionary lines I get this error:

```
choices = ['s','m','o','k','e','j','a','c','k']
def parsed(choices): 
    mySet = {}

    for item in choices: 
        filename = self.location + "/dicts/%s.txt" % (item)
            mySet.update(open(filename).read().splitlines())

    return mySet
```

I get this error

```
error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

Furthermore, I'd like to ask if there's a possible comparison method between two sets of data (9 character permutations, and 9 dictionary files list) that runs in less than 1 minute.

I understand that there are already questions regarding this error, but frankly I'm a beginner and I don't understand how those relate to my code, or how to fix it.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions should contain one question - that's to make them more useful for future readers. But regarding your "furthermore", on my 2GHz 32 bit machine I can test all permutations of "SMOKEJACK" against the [sowpods Scrabble dictionary](http://www.3zsoftware.com/download) of 216553 words in around 1.5 seconds. FWIW, I found no anagrams apart from "SMOKEJACK" itself.

Comment: I see, now I know it's possible. I have rewritten this code and will open another question specifically asking about the time question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: use `itertools.permutations` to generate the permutations, and _don't_ store them in a list or set: just test them against your set of words as you generate them. And it probably would be faster to build the set of words if you read them from a single file containing all the words rather than having separate files for each initial letter.

Comment: I have created a separate question now (/questions/42205319/find-all-matches-of-permutations-within-allotted-time). I would be awfully thankful if you could elaborate on how to do that in that question, as I am still a beginner and find it hard to understand how I should do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you write:

```
mySet = {}
```

`mySet` is **not a `set`, but a dictionary** (yeah that is confusing). For instance:

```
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
```

In order to construct an empty set, you should use:

```
mySet = set()
```

A `set` indeed has a function `update` that takes as input an iterable of elements that are all added to the set. A dictionary on the other hand requires an iterable of tuples (or a dictionary, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I've been wrecking my head at this for hours.